# Windows7 - Wifi / Network - Slow detection time

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I am using `Lenova W50` - laptop. my platform is `windows7`. the issue is, when i switch between `wifi` to `network` or `network` to `wifi` - the system taking long time to detect the availability of the networks.

to find the `wifi` it takes minimum 20 min. ( show not `wifi` available )

what is the issue here? how to solve this?

[image: I have added the status of my wifi]

Comment: Are you just now experiencing this issue? or have you recently purchased this laptop or upgraded it?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue after this laptop handover from my college to me from last 2 months ( actually this is reformatted before handover to me )

Comment: Can you ensure you have the correct driver for the wifi/network card and not just something windows 7 through on there such as a generic driver? And also is this the W530 or W500 cant find a Lenovo W50

Comment: this is W520 lenovo series. sorry for typo